# Does this imply $A+B\sim D_A+D_B?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a symmetric matrix $A$ be similar to diagonal matrix $D_A$ and a symmetric matrix $B$ be similar to diagonal matrix $D_B.$ Does this imply $A+B\sim D_A+D_B?$

Answer (score 5):

Of course not. Consider $A=D_A=D_B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=-A$.

Answer (score 3):

For another example, take
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} = D_{A},
$$
and
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = D_{B}.
$$
Now
$$
A + B = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
is non-singular, so it cannot be similar to
$$
D_A + D_B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is singular.